# LINQ to Entity, subquery with navigation property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have two EF classes - one is called `event` and another `user`.

`event` contains many fields related to an event that is being run, and has been generated by Entity Framework (v6 I think). `user` models a user object.

`event` contains a navigation property, which is a list of the users who have signed up to attend the event.

What I am trying to do is filter the list of users so that it contains either no entry (user_id x did not book), or it contains one entry (user_id x did book).

What I have at the moment is:

`var evts = context.events.Where(e=>event_id<10);` which lists the first ten events.

`events` has a navigation property called `user_bookings` which is a list of `user` - how do I filter the users so that I can only attach the users with a supplied user_id?

**EDIT**

To clarify (I don't think I did a good job explaining) - I want the list of events regardless of whether a user has signed up for the event or not. What I'm trying to do is limit the list of users returned by the LINQ to either no user (current user hasn't booked this event) or one user (current user has booked it).

Comment: There is a problem with something like context.users.Where(x => x.Events.Count <=1) ?

Comment: What I'm trying to replace is something akin to this SQL: `select e.*, (select count(*) from event_user_booking b where e.event_id=b.event_id and b.user_id=@user_id) from event e where e.event_id<10`

As Entity Framework created my objects, the table event_user_booking isn't included as an object because it was just a lookup table to resolve a many-many relationship between event and user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a full list of events for a user with a given `user_id`, with an indication whether the user has booked for that event, you can do the following:

```
var user_id = 10; // example
var query = 
    from evt in context.events 
    select new {
        Event = evt,
        HasBooked = evt.user_bookings.Any(x => x.user_id == user_id)
    };
```

If you want to limit this to a maximum `event_id` (e.g. all that are smaller than 10), you can modify this to:

```
var user_id = 10; // example
var event_id_upper_limit = 10;
var query = 
    from evt in context.events 
    where evt.event_id < event_id_upper_limit
    select new {
        Event = evt,
        HasBooked = evt.user_bookings.Any(x => x.user_id == user_id)
    };
```

Comment: Hi. What I'm after is a full list of events, and either zero or one user in the user_bookings result.

I want to be able to show the list of events, and a link that either says 'register' or 'registered' depending on whether a particular user has already registered. 

I'm playing with EF, LINQ and MVC for the first time here - trying to achieve as much as possible with as little coding as possible. (I always thought SQL was fine and can do this no problem with SQL, but trying to learn something new).

Comment: So, this is great. Does it mean I lose the advantages of strongly-typed views if i use this in an MVC project? What type of data is now returned, as before it would have been a set of `event` objects.

Comment: @ChrisK, you can create a new type (e.g. `UserEventBookingStatus`) that contains these two fields (and possibly also include a `UserId` field) instead of returning an anonymous object.